# How to connect QPlainText to ComboBox in Qt

Tags: qt

With regards to Qt, I have a question.
I want the user to write a word in Plain Edit Text box. Once the word is written and the cursor is removed from that box, I want that word to be saved in ComboBox. How can one achieve this?

Comment: Assumed that you are using `QLineEdit` as the edit text box, there is a signal `editingFinished` which you can connect to a slot, and which then adds the current content of the `QLineEdit` to your drop down box.

Comment: Yes, I am using QLineEdit and now my question is "once I connect editingFinished signal to the slot, how can the current content of the QLineEdit be added to the drop down menu (ComboBox)?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can the current content of the QLineEdit be added to the drop down menu (ComboBox)?

Assumed that you have a class which has the `QLineEdit` and the `QComboBox` as members, and which also has a slot which is connected to the `updateDropdown()` method, like

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT;

    QLineEdit* lineEdit;
    QComboBox* dropDown;

// ...

public slots:
    void updateDropdown();
};
```

you can simply use

```
void MainWindow::updateDropdown() {
   dropDown->addItem(lineEdit->text());
}
```

Comment: This looks like it should work but there is no signal specifying the update of ComboBox in 'go to slot' menu and so where does updateDropdown()  comes from?

Comment: Are you talking about QtDesigner (Are you creating your UI with QtDesigner)? `updateDropdown()` is a method you need to implement on your own - It is similar to what @TheBadger shows in his anwer, with the difference that he uses an anonymous function (a lambda expression) which contains the one line of code which actually does the job. That is a C++11 feature though and it depends on your environment whether you can use it.

Comment: I am trying the code below where the item needs to be added to the combo box once user finishes typing on line edit. the program is getting crashed every time I finish typing in the line edit.

`void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_editingFinished()
{
    comboBox->addItem(lineEdit->text());
}`

Comment: Update: The problem got solved. I forgot to add the right heaaders :(
Thanks @Andreas

Answer (score 2):

Connect the editingFinished signal on the edit to a slot (either a custom slot on your class or a lambda function as below) and in that slot get the text from the edit and add it to the items in the box.

Lets assume you have c++11:

```
QComboBox *myBox;
QLineEdit *myEdit;

connect(myEdit, &QLineEdit::editingFinished, [myBox, myEdit](){ 
    myBox->addItem(myEdit->text());
});
```

You need to update the code according to your application, but the above should give you the idea and guidance that you need.